# What is the opposite of "Coexist"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there a good phrase or word that means the opposite of "coexist"?

The phrase I am using it in is similar to "these two ideas need not (be) *_*_."

Comment: *Contradictory*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Mutually exclusive

Two things that can't happen at the same time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_exclusive_events

Answer (score -1):

"These two (noun)s need not ***_*____**"

Some ideas:

1. Disagree
2. Differ
3. Conflict
4. Contradict

Answer (score -2):

Depends on the context but in many instances the opposite of *coexistence* is *persecution*.

Comment: _Persecution_ isn't suitable for the context given in the question, grammatically or semantically.

Comment: Also, *exist* derives from Latin *existĕre*, which you will note is a Latin conjugation other than the 1st (*-are*) conjugation — and therefore does not take *-ance* in English but rather *-ence*. These things matter.

Comment: I didn't read the phrase. Yes, given the context, "persecution" is not a valid answer.

Answer (score -2):

"disparate" comes to mind. Fundamentally distinct or different in kind; entirely dissimilar:

"diametrically opposed" also comes to mind.

how about "at odds?" or "Immiscible".

or "irreconcilable"?